# What happens when __init__() gets some arguments

Tags: python, oop, init

What's the diffeernce between `super(SomeClass, self).__init__()` AND `super(SomeClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`? The first one initializes the constructor of the parent, **but what about the second one?**

Comment: This question keeps cropping up. The answer is the same each and every time, you are getting hung up over the `*args` and `**kwargs` syntax, not about `__init__` methods here.

Comment: See [Argument List Unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for your comment. I actually know about those STARS, and I have already told that. I am not a pro programmer, but it doesn't mean that I am too stupid to ask the same question again and again. Look at my elected BEST ANSWER, it clearly answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one calls the superclass' constructor *with arguments*.

Some demonstration:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, karg1=None, karg2=None):
...             print arg1, arg2, karg1, karg2
... 
>>> b = Base(1, 2, karg2='a')
1 2 None a
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...             super(Derived, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> d = Derived(1, 2, karg1='Hello, world!')
1 2 Hello, world! None

>>> class Derived2(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(Derived2, self).__init__()        # this will fail because Base.__init__ does not have a no-argument signature
... 
>>> d2 = Derived2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

`super(SomeClass, self)` returns a proxy object that stands in for some class (*not* necessarily the parent of `SomeClass`, if multiple inheritance is involved). As such, you need to pass the appropriate argument to its `__init__` method. If it expects arguments, the first will fail. If it expects no arguments, the second one *may* fail, if `args` and `kwargs` aren't already empty.